# How Can I Clear Display from NSString after Button Up Touch?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, button, nsstring

I have a label which reads as

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"]];

UILabel *testLabel =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65,50,200,50)]; // RectMake(xPos,yPos,Max Width I want, is just a container value);

NSString *test=@"I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.  What is it?";

testLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];
testLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
testLabel.text = test;
testLabel.numberOfLines = 0; //will wrap text in new line
[testLabel sizeToFit];

[self.view addSubview:testLabel];
```

At the end of this ViewController.m page I have a button pushed after a user submits the field value:

```
- (IBAction)guessNow:(id)sender {


self.usersGuess = self.guessNumberField.text;


NSString *guessString = self.usersGuess;

if ([guessString length] == 0) {

    guessString = @"Really No Guess? Try Again.";

}

   //_testLabel.text = @""; attempting to clear out label when user submits the value
NSString *guessReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Good try but %@ is not the answer!", guessString];

self.testLabel.text = guessReply;


}
```

The problem is when a user enters the value in the field and hit the guess button, the answer is showing up behind the initial field value.  Here is a screenshot:

[image]

How can I clear out the initial message so only the reply shows up?

Comment: lots of great answers here.  I am evalutating this feedback and will post an update soon.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have to separate UILabels. In your viewDidLoad method you are initializing new UILabel, setting its properties and than you are adding it to self.view.subviews but in guessNow: method you are setting string to self.testLabel.text property and this is not the same UILabel! You should change your viewDidLoad method to:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"]];

self.testLabel =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65,50,200,50)];

NSString *test=@"I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.  What is it?";

self.testLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];
self.testLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.testLabel.text = test;
self.testLabel.numberOfLines = 0; //will wrap text in new line
[self.testLabel sizeToFit];

[self.view addSubview:self.testLabel];
```

If your self.testLabel is IBOutlet connected to UILabel in Storyboard, than you should omit these two lines in your code:

```
self.testLabel =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65,50,200,50)];
...
...
...
[self.view addSubview:self.testLabel];
```

Comment: Yes!  Thanks, that fixed it.  I had to omit those two lines as you noted.  Could you please give me a bit more background as to why these omissions fixed my problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Interface Builder. Hold Ctrl button down click the button (Button that will handle clearing the text) and drag to your implementation View Controller. A small window will appear  shows Touch Up from the drop down menu and name the method then tap enter.

An empty method will be created. Clear text inside:

```
- (IBAction)clearText:(id)sender {
     self.testLabel.text = @"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here is that you are not properly reusing the Label... The instructions as well as the guess Should be written in the same label. (without re-adding it to the subview) you can simply use the self.labelname.text=@"newLabel".

The code you provided doesnt matchup with the result...

Comment: I agree that I am missing the seamless connection between the initial label and the one that is updated when the button is clicked.  I thought that I was matching it up in the second example from the question where I state this line `self.testLabel.text = guessReply;`  Should I move the guessNow method to a different location?